# Error while calling contract entry point on Carthagenet

Tags: carthagenet

When I send this parameter in a call to a smart contract entry point on Carthagenet, it fails. Nevertheless, on Babylonnet it used to work:

{"entrypoint":"default","value":{"args":[{"args":[{"args":[{"args":[{"args":[{"int":"3000000"},{"string":"11111111"}],"prim":"Pair"},{"string":"Stuart"}],"prim":"Pair"},{"int":"33333333"}],"prim":"Pair"}],"prim":"Left"}],"prim":"Left"}}

The JSON is valid (checked with a JSON prettifier tool) and it is just like the one generated by SmartPy's explorer. Just one difference is the order of the JSON elements (i.e.: instead of {"prim":"Left", "args":[]}, I have: {"args":[], "prim":"Left"})

Answer (score 0):

I think the contract you call on Carthagenet has a slightly different interface than the one you used to work with on Babylonnet. Can you give both KT1 addresses?

You can convert a JSON-encoded Michelson expression to the usual (and much more readable) Micheline format using `tezos-client convert data file.json from JSON to Micheline`.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Caudelier. I will check details again.